# How Can I Install sweetalert2 via Laravel-Mix?

Tags: laravel, npm, laravel-mix, sweetalert2

STEP1: In console/terminal.

```
npm install --save sweetalert2
```

STEP2: In app.scss add this line...

```
@import '~sweetalert2/src/sweetalert2.scss';
```

STEP3: In app.js add this line...

```
const swal = require('sweetalert2');
```

STEP4: In webpack.min.js...

```
mix.setPublicPath('public');
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'js');
mix.sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'css');
```

STEP5: `npm run dev`

STEP6: Add app.js and app.css to HTML document

I got this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: swal is not defined

What's the missing step?

Comment: where is this error appearing? I'm guessing it's not app.js and you defined swal in app.js.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to make it available anywhere you would have to tie it to the window:

```
const swal = window.swal = require('sweetalert2');
```

But a better way would be to include it in any file you use it in, the same way you did in `app.js`

Answer (score 1):

Update `/resources/js/bootstrap.js.`

```
try {
    window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

    require('sweetalert2');
    require('bootstrap');
} catch (e) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this in bootstrap.js add :

```
try {
    window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

    const Swal = window.Swal = require('sweetalert2');

    require('bootstrap');

} catch (e) {}
```

in app.sass add

```
@import "~sweetalert2/src/sweetalert2";
```